# algebra linear, matrix, alexei kostrikin

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that the equation XY - YX = E cannot be solved in terms of finite
square matrices X, Y over a field with a zero characteristic. (Hint: examine the
trace of both parts.) Find the solution of this equation in terms of infinite matrices.
(Hint: study the linear operators d/dx and multiplication by x on the space of all
polynomials of x and use the fact that d(xf)/dx - x*d(f)/dx = f .)

Comment: What do you know about the traces of $XY$ and $YX$?

Comment: Nothing
Just ask to prove it...

Comment: How about writing out the trace of $XY$ in terms of the entries of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Oh, the first question is easy to demonstrate with the trace on both sides.
But the second part of the question about the infinite matrix is ​​complicated...

Comment: Just write down the matrices of multiplication by $x$ and $d/dx$ w.r.t. the basis $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: The hint on the second part is really quite comprehensive. How about expressing those linear operators in terms of a basis for the space of polynomials?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What's the advantage of writing the operators out in terms of a basis?  I would think it suffices to prove the points from the hint.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown what's the advantage of writing the operators out in terms of a basis?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The question does ask for matrices...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown oooh you're right